# Why this program prints 0?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, minimum, minimum-size

I am supposed to write a program that prints the minimum value from vector.This is what i tried. It only prints 0. I tried to change the sign both ways but it doesnt work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int read(int v[], int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        scanf("%i", &v[i]);
        i++;
    } while (v[i-1] != 0 && i < size);
    int n = i;
    return n;
}
   
int minim(int v[], int n)
{
    int m;
    m = v[0];
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= n-1; i++)
    {
        if (v[i] < m)
        {
            m = v[i];           
        }     
    }
    return m;  
}

int main()
{
    int arr[100];
    int n = read(arr, 100);
      
    int min = minim(arr, n);
    printf("\nMinimum vrom vector is %i\n", min);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your exit condition is `while(v[i-1]!=0 && ..)` so unless you entered 100 values by hand, you must have entered a 0 to end the read process, hence the 0? You should also check whether `scanf` returns a value, it might not be reading anything at all.

Comment: I am using an example from our teacher. It works perfectly for maximum. But i only changed the comparison sign from minimum function. And it print 0.

Comment: Aside: instead of `i<=n-1` use the idiomatic `i < n` which is easier to read and less open to error.

Comment: Mary, with input `"1" Enter`, `"2" Enter`, `"3" Enter`, `"0" Enter`, the minimum is 0 and the maximum is 3.  Why is that surprising?

Comment: try for positive non zero numbers

Comment: Why do you want to exit the loop when ```0``` is successfully processed and converted by ```scanf```? The condition doesn't make sense. ```0``` would always be the minimum unless you had entered negative numbers.

Comment: I omitted the last element ```0``` and compiled your code. It worked perfectly, even for ```55 66 54 64```.

Comment: specifically i am trying to make it work for positive, non zero.  55 66 54 64 for example

Comment: i am trying now

Comment: I am sorr Harris, can you show me what exactly did write? I must be doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

Since your `scanf` loop (I'd recommend staying away from function names like `read`, which are part of the C standard, even if you didn't include `unistd.h`) ends when 0 is entered, you need to include a check at the end to decrement the size of the array if 0 is the last entry.  Basically, replace everything after your do-while loop with this:

```
if (v[i - 1]) {
    return i;
}
return --i;
```

This will return `i` if all 100 elements are non-zero, otherwise it will decrement to remove the 0 from your array before returning.  No need to declare `int n=i` just to instantly `return n`.

Edit: I saw your comment that it worked properly for finding the maximum.  This is because you almost certainly entered a number into the array that's greater than 0, so adding 0 at the end would not affect the maximum number.  Try finding the max again, but only enter negative numbers.  The result will be 0.

Comment: it doesnt seem to work for 55 66 54 64. We have an automatic compiler at school. It works for 2 cases but it doesnt work for 55 66 54 64

Comment: int read_array (int v[],int size)
   {
       int i=0;
       do
          {
              scanf("%i",&v[i]);
              i++;
          } while  (v[i-1]!=0 && i<size);
      if (v[i - 1]) {
    return i;
}
return --i;
   }

Comment: It's still giving you 0?  Or the wrong answer?  That shouldn't be happening.

Comment: 0 is not entered because i can see exactly for what cases it should work. They are only positive and non zero.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Which cases are working, if that isn't?  I can't see any other errors, and can't get to a computer to test it.

Comment: try to see if it works for 55 66 54 64

Comment: I just tested that and it works fine.  I'm not sure what your error is.

Comment: i am probably not modifying it the right way

Comment: Could you be kind enough to write the whole read function?

Comment: What you pasted earlier is fine.  Are you using a website like Cengage, by chance?  They often have funky requirements that might be causing the failure.

Comment: I am using a compiler from our school. It automathically adds input and output. I think everybody is giving me right answers. Unfortunately they dont seem to work on that specifically compiler

Answer (score 0):

`read()` uses a `0` entry to terminate reading more input.  Yet that 0 is included in the array and counts toward the array length as part of the return value.

Instead, only increment the array count when input was numeric and non-zero.

```
int read(int v[], int size) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < size) {
        // Also test if valid numeric input was read.
        if (scanf("%i", &v[i]) != 1) {
            break;
        }
        // Stop if a 0 was read
        if (v[i] == 0) {
            break;
        }
        // Now increment
        i++;
    }
   
    return i;
}
```

Could use shorter code, yet it is less readable.  Best to code for clarity.

```
int read(int v[], int size) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < size && scanf("%i", &v[i]) == 1 && v[i]) {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The test condition

```
while (v[i-1] != 0
```

checks whether the last element read was `0`, after it was successfully processed and converted by `scanf` (but you never checked the return value). The `0` is then included in the array, and will always be the minimum unless you enter a non-negative number.

Here's the working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
    
static size_t read (int v[], size_t size)
{
      size_t i = 0;
      do
      {
          /* Check if scanf was successful */ 
          if (scanf("%i",&v[i]) != 1) {
              fprintf(stderr, "Error: Invalid input.\n"); 
              return EXIT_FAILURE;
          }
       
      } while (v[i] != 0 && ++i < size);

      return i;
 }
       
static int minim (int v[],size_t n)
{
     int min;
     min = v[0];
           
     for(size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            if (v[i] < min) {
                min = v[i]; 
            }        
     }
     return min;  
}

int main(void)
{
     int arr[100];
     size_t n = read(arr,100);
                
     int min = minim(arr,n);
     printf("\nMinimum vrom vector is %i\n", min);
     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }
```

I made some minor changes to it. Though I'm not satisfied with the design.

### Sample I/O:

```
20
8
18
60
39
56
0
Minimum vrom vector is 8
```

Comment: Unfortunately on our university compiler doesnt work. But thank you for your patience, I am sure that is a good code

Comment: What compiler is it? What errors or warnings did it provide? What difficulty are you facing?

Comment: Minimum vrom vector is 6

***Run error***
Error: Invalid input.

Comment: The size is 6. Could it be that i dont read the size in my code?

Comment: Mary, I can't infer from that information what's wrong with your code. You should add all the details in your question.

Comment: Haris, Instead of `i++; } while (v[i - 1] != 0 && i < size); if (v[i - 1] == 0) {  i--;  }`, could use simpler  `while (v[i] != 0 && ++i < size);`.  Either work OK as long as `size != 0`.